# How to write SFINAE to test for parser rule?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a sfinae class that tests whether a class is a parser rule (AXE parser generator library).
The `axe::is_rule<P>::value` should evaluate to true iff P satisfies parser rule requirements. A parser rule must have one of the following member functions, taking a pair of iterators and returning [`axe::result<Iterator>`:](http://www.gbresearch.com/axe/Dox/axe__result_8h_source.html#l00016)

```
template<class Iterator>
axe::result<Iterator> P::operator()(Iterator, Iterator);
```

, or its specialization, or non-template for some type CharT

```
axe::result<CharT*> P::operator()(CharT*, CharT*);
```

, or const versions of the above. Theoretically, there can be more than one overloaded `operator()`, though in practice a test for a single `operator()` with one of the above signatures would suffice.

Unfortunately, current implementation of [`is_rule`](http://www.gbresearch.com/axe/Dox/axe__trait_8h_source.html#l00018) takes care of only some, but not all cases. There are some unfortunate classes, that fail the `is_rule` test:

```
#define AXE_ASSERT_RULE(T)\
    static_assert(axe::is_rule<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type>::value, \
    "type '" #T "' is not a rule");
```

For example, the following unfortunate types fail the test:

```
struct unfortunate 
{ 
   axe::result<const unsigned char*> 
   operator()(const unsigned char*, const unsigned char*); 
};

AXE_ASSERT_RULE(unfortunate);

// or same using lambda
auto unfortunate1 = [](const unsigned char*, const unsigned char*)
->axe::result<const unsigned char*> {};
AXE_ASSERT_RULE(decltype(unfortunate1));


typedef std::vector<char>::iterator vc_it;
struct unfortunate2 { axe::result<vc_it> operator()(vc_it, vc_it) const; };
AXE_ASSERT_RULE(unfortunate2);

typedef axe::result<const char*> (unfortunate3)(const char*, const char*);
AXE_ASSERT_RULE(unfortunate3);

struct rule { template<class I> axe::result<I> operator()(I, I); };
class unfortunate4 : public rule {};
AXE_ASSERT_RULE(unfortunate4);
```

Current solution in AXE is to wrap those in a forwarding wrapper ([`class r_ref_t`](http://www.gbresearch.com/axe/Dox/axe__composite_8h_source.html#l00197)), which, of course, creates syntactic warts (after all, parser generator is all about syntactic sugar).

How would you modify the sfinae test in `is_rule` to cover the unfortunate cases above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the API of `is_rule` is not sufficient.  For example `unfortunate` is a rule only if used with iterators of type `const unsigned char*`.  If you use `unfortunate` with `const char*`, then it doesn't work, and is thus not a rule, right?

That being said, if you change the API to:

```
template <class R, class It> struct is_rule;
```

then I think this is doable in C++11.  Below is a prototype:

```
#include <type_traits>

namespace axe
{

template <class It>
struct result
{
};

}

namespace detail
{

struct nat
{
    nat() = delete;
    nat(const nat&) = delete;
    nat& operator=(const nat&) = delete;
    ~nat() = delete;
};

struct any
{
    any(...);

    nat operator()(any, any) const;
};

template <class T>
struct wrap
    : public any,
      public T
{
};

template <bool, class R, class It>
struct is_rule
{
     typedef typename std::conditional<std::is_const<R>::value,
                                      const wrap<R>,
                                      wrap<R>>::type W;

   typedef decltype(
                std::declval<W>()(std::declval<It>(), std::declval<It>())
                    ) type;

    static const bool value = std::is_convertible<type, axe::result<It>>::value;
};

template <class R, class It>
struct is_rule<false, R, It>
{
    static const bool value = false;
};

}  // detail

template <class R, class It>
struct is_rule
    : public std::integral_constant<bool,
                         detail::is_rule<std::is_class<R>::value, R, It>::value>
{
};

struct unfortunate 
{ 
   axe::result<const unsigned char*> 
   operator()(const unsigned char*, const unsigned char*); 
};

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << is_rule<unfortunate, const unsigned char*>::value << '\n';
    std::cout << is_rule<unfortunate, const char*>::value << '\n';
}
```

For me this prints out:

```
1
0
```

I made the rule slightly more lax than you specified:  The return type only has to be implicitly convertible to `axe::result<It>`.  If you really want it to be exactly `axe::result<It>` then just sub in `std::is_same` where I used `std::is_convertible`.

I also made `is_rule` derive from `std::integral_constant`.  This can be very convenient for tag dispatching.  E.g.:

```
template <class T>
void imp(T, std::false_type);

template <class T>
void imp(T, std::true_type);

template <class T>
void foo(T t) {imp(t, is_rule<T, const char*>());}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `is_rule` class cannot take an iterator type, because there is no way to specify it. When a rule expression is created, iterator type is unknown and cannot be specified. For example, (operator& see http://tinyurl.com/3kmmcmh) in expression `auto rule = A & B;` is iterator agnostic, rules A and B can take various iterator forms or be composite rules themselves, but I must be able to call `rule(i1, i2)` for any compatible iterator. As long as all rules implement templatized `operator()` I'm fine, otherwise (importantly with lambda functions) the `is_rule` test unfortunately fails.

Comment: If you want to nail down a finite set of iterators you could modify the above to check against any of that finite set of iterators, and return true if the rule works for any of the set of iterators.

Comment: I see what you mean. It would seriously inflate the code, each composite rule (and there are many) would have to test all possible combination of all possible iterators for each parameter. Like this: `template<class R1, class R2>
r_and_t<
typename std::enable_if<is_rule<typename std::remove_reference<R1>::type, It1>::value
| is_rule<typename std::remove_reference<R1>::type, It2>::value, 
R1>::type, 
typename std::enable_if<is_rule<typename std::remove_reference<R2>::type, It1>::value
| is_rule<typename std::remove_reference<R2>::type, It2>::value, 
R2>::type
>
operator& (R1&& r1, R2&& r2);`...

Comment: If you want to force the rule to have a templated operator you could define an iterator (of some value_type?) in `detail{}` and then test against that.  Writing `is_rule` really forces you to think carefully about the precise specifications for a rule! :-)

Comment: Yes, I know, precise specification of what is a rule is somewhat elusive :-) I started with "everything, derived from a specified class Rule" to be a rule, which was simple to implement, until I realized I needed lambdas and free functions to be rules too, so I had to come with a test. On one hand `is_rule` should be as broad as possible to accomodate all practical possibilities, on the other hand to be as narrow as possible to provide useful overloading and prevent matching everything, like in `template<class R1, class R2> r_and_t<R1,R2> operator& (R1&& r1, R2&& r2);`

Comment: Final comment, then I'll leave you alone. :-)  C++11 makes it much easier to write your traits using expressions instead of types.  You still have to use types of course to create your expressions.  But often a trait is asking if some expression is going to work or not.  And it is much easier to express that definition directly in your trait in C++11.  Just this past week I wrote a trait `invokable<T, Args...>::value` that models all 5 bullets of 20.8.2 [func.require]/p1 in the C++11 standard.  I was truly amazed at how easy and straightforward it was, using expressions.

Comment: @HowardHinnant : Is your `invokable<>` trait hosted online anywhere? It sounds like something that would come in handy!

Comment: Yes, but it is encumbered with a generous open source copyright.  Keep the copyright with the source code and you can do with it whatever you want.  I wrote it in support of libc++ (http://libcxx.llvm.org/).  Follow the "browse svn" link and look at include/type_traits.  Because it is currently an implementation detail, it is spelled `__invokable`.  There is also a matching `__invoke_of` that I think of as what we wanted `result_of` to do, but didn't quite make it.  `__invoke_of` is designed to be its own "enable_if".  That is, the nested type won't exist if the expression isn't invokable.